# Angular2 - Add class to element with a particular id

Tags: angular

I want to add a class to element with a particular id in Angular 2.

In JavaScript, here is how it's done, but I don't have an idea on how to do it in Angular2.

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " active";
```

So far, I have this:

```
<div id="1" [class.active]="conditionIsHere">div 1</div>
<div id="2" [class.active]="conditionIsHere">div 2</div>
```

Comment: can you explain your scenario there may be better solution for that, as Angular 2 has very good data-binding capabilities.

Comment: What's the problem with "So far, I have this: ..."?

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="1" [class.active]="activeId == 1" (click)="activeId=1">div 1</div>
<div id="2" [class.active]="activeId == 2" (click)="activeId=2">div 2</div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  activeId:number;
}
```